# "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter error from retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm attempting to use retrofit2 for the first time. I read online many tutorials and read the docs. I understand the steps and didn't expect any errors ;) but when I run the app, I get the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for 
java.util.List<com.example.myretrofit.MarsPhoto>                                                                                                
for method MarsApiService.getPhotos
```

I used the create app with noActivity so my code is the basic code but added retrofit on top of the file. I just wanted to try retrofit and initiating a get call to an api.

Here is the code MainActivity.kt using kotlinx.serilization for json and retrofit2 for http get:

```
package com.example.myretrofit

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.myretrofit.ui.theme.MyRetrofitTheme

//retrofit implementation
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.asConverterFactory
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.GET
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import retrofit2.Call
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString

/**
 * This data class defines a Mars photo which includes an ID, and the image URL.
 */
@Serializable
data class MarsPhoto(
    val id: String,
    @SerialName(value = "img_src")
    val imgSrc: String
)

private const val BASE_URL =
    "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com"

/**
 * Use the Retrofit builder to build a retrofit object using a kotlinx.serialization converter
 */
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

/**
 * Retrofit service object for creating api calls
 */
interface MarsApiService {
    @GET("photos")
    fun getPhotos(): List<MarsPhoto>
}

/**
 * A public Api object that exposes the lazy-initialized Retrofit service
 */
object MarsApi {
    val retrofitService: MarsApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(MarsApiService::class.java)
    }
}


//end of retrofit implementation

val listResult = MarsApi.retrofitService.getPhotos()

//                    for (item in listResult) {
//                        Log.i("ServerItem : ", "$item")
//                    }


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyRetrofitTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    val listResult = MarsApi.retrofitService.getPhotos()

                    Log.i("ServerItem : ", "print something")
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    MyRetrofitTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Clearly I missed something while reading all the tutorials and docs for retrofit2.
The error indicates that the interface code is wrong but I don't know why? I don't have an adapter and I actually don't need an adapter with kotlinx.serilization, right??

How to fix this error so I can get the response from the api?

The docs is [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#libraries)

Please keep in mind that I'm at level 0 in android studio/kotlin/apps development. I just started three weeks ago. I understand and able to use compose well. I understand how to work with activities and coroutines. I don't want to add coRoutines here because I wanted to understand retrofit2 so I'm ok with the call blocking the thread.

I believe the error is because the interface is fun getPhotos() when I take it out, the error goes away, the app runs correctly but I get nothing from the retrofit instance. No logging of any type.

Thank you for trying to help.

How to fix this error so I can get the response from the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kotlinx.serialization` is not officially available as a converter factory for Retrofit. If you still want to use it with Retrofit you need to use this [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter).

However, I would suggest an easier option like `GsonConverter` which is available for Retrofit. To do this, first, add the dependency:

```kotlin
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:<your_retrofit_version>")
```

And then, add the converter factory when creating the Retrofit client:

```kotlin
Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl("<your_api_base_url>")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
```

For a more detailed usecase in a project with dependency injection check out [this](https://github.com/atick-faisal/Jetpack-Compose-Starter/tree/main/network/src/main/kotlin/dev/atick/network).

Comment: Thank you, Atick. I'll try it and see how far I can go.  I took a look at your portofolio on Github. Impressive work.

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks for checking out my GitHub. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Atick, I tried the GsonConverterFactory and I was able to get the data from the api but I'm stuck iterating over the result and displaying it in compose. Whenever you have the time, could you help with this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77896509/how-to-display-response-data-from-retrofit-body-in-compose

Comment: Never mind. Someone else helped me. I appreciate your help. Thank you.,