# How to display response data from retrofit body in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
package com.example.retrofit1

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.retrofit1.ui.theme.Retrofit1Theme


import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
//import retrofit2.create


import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

// retrofit try geeksforgeeks
// data class QuoteList
// according to JSON response








// Retrofit interface



//import retrofit2.http.Query

interface QuotesApi {
    @GET("/quotes")
    suspend fun getQuotes() : Response<QuoteList>
}

object RetrofitHelper {

    val baseUrl = "https://quotable.io/"

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            // we need to add converter factory to
            // convert JSON object to Java object
            .build()
    }
}

data class Result(
    val _id: String,
    val author: String,
    val authorSlug: String,
    val content: String,
    val dateAdded: String,
    val dateModified: String,
    val length: Int,
    val tags: List<String>
)
data class QuoteList(
    val count: Int,
    val lastItemIndex: Int,
    val page: Int,
    val results: List<Result>,
    val totalCount: Int,
    val totalPages: Int
)



class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val quotesApi = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(QuotesApi::class.java)
        // launching a new coroutine
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val result = quotesApi.getQuotes()
            if (result != null) {
                // Checking the results
                Log.d("result: ", result.message().toString())
                //debug
                // How to display count = 20 or lastItemIndex = 20 from the 
                //  QuoteList
                Log.d("count: ", result.body().toString())

                //warning
                Log.w("myApp", "count  --")

            }
        }


        setContent {
            Retrofit1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    Retrofit1Theme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
```

I see in the logcat the data:

```
QuoteList(count=20, lastItemIndex=20, page=1, results=[Result(_id=bfNpGC2NI, author=Thomas Edison, authorSlug=thomas-edison, content=As a cure for worrying, work is better than whisky., dateAdded=2023-04-14, dateModified=2023-04-14, length=51, tags=[Humorous]),...etc
```

You can find the api [page data here](https://quotable.io/quotes?page=1)

How to deconstruct the data and display it in my compose as text?

Something like this :

```
Count : 20
Author : Thomas Edison
Quote : "As a cure for worrying, work is better than whisky."
```

So, I come from js where I would do result.count and it display 20
But in kotlin with data class and quotelist in this example, how do I access the data inside the result.body()???

I intentionally used one file so I can show all the code in one place and can follow what you will explain to me so I can learn. I also used the project with no activity so I didn't alter anything in the original code generated by the android studio. I just added the retrofit code.

I know some of you will laugh at this question but there are beginners out there and need help. Thanks for trying to help. Your contribution to the community is valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the cuff, if we stick with your approach, you would do something like:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val quotesState: MutableState<QuoteList?> by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

        val quotesApi = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(QuotesApi::class.java)
        // launching a new coroutine
        GlobalScope.launch {
            quotesState = quotesApi.getQuotes()
        }

        setContent {
            Retrofit1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting(quotesState)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`Greeting()` would then use the `QuoteList` however you wish (e.g., `LazyColumn()`).

Note that between books and blog posts, there is a *lot* written about Compose, including using Retrofit with Compose, such as [this](https://medium.com/@jecky999/building-an-android-app-with-jetpack-compose-retrofit-and-mvvm-architecture-12a5e03eb03a).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll tinker around and see how far I can go. How do I log.d(QuoteList.count) or log.d(QuoteList.content)?

Comment: @Marco: Um, well, assuming your parameter in `Greeting()` is named `quoteList`, `Log.d("SomeTag", "count: ${quoteList.count}")` would work. You have nothing on a `QuoteList` named `content` AFAICT.

Comment: Sorry. content was under results. Thank you so much.